# No device is showing after initialising ADB Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

It was working perfectly but after a restart it do not showing any device (virtual or Connected) rather it shows a message Nothing to show 
[image: ADB]

any reasons?

Comment: have you an AVD set up?

Comment: Yes I do have may AVD set up

Comment: did you start a new project? Maybe your AVD API level is not suitable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start debugging like below -

1) Make sure you have USB debugging option enabled under 'Setting->System->Developer options".

2) Make sure you have the path for adb executable added in Windows environment variable. mostly located at -
 C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools

3) Connect your phone USB in your PC and go to Device Manager. Make sure you have USB driver installed which is needed for ADB connection. It should look similar like the picture below.

[image]

4) Just in case if your device manger doesn't connect the ADB you will at least see some port (most likely USB port) with warning sign. This indicates that your windows detected the H/W but no driver installed yet.
In this case please follow the link below - 
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb.html

5) Once you install the driver via SDK or from inf file from the link provided in STEP 2, you should be able to see the device in Device Manager and after this point your Android studio should show the device in your android studio.

Comment: Don't know what happened it fixed first but then same error is occuring

Comment: If you still have these issues I would again insist to go through the debug steps and check which step it is failing. Some additional thoughts coming to my mind to see if you have any permission issues (Administrator vs normal user), or weather you can see the device using "adb devices" on command prompt or Android Studio Terminal.